# Netlogo: Call commands from text files?

Tags: netlogo

Is it possible to call commands from a text file?
The goal I am trying to achieve is to have a text file with strings of commands ,the user can input this file in and the system will then call the commands.
What I have so far is from studying the file input example is:

```
 to load-test
    let file user-file
    file-open file
    let lines []
    while [not file-at-end?]
    [
        let a-line file-read 
        set lines lput a-line lines
    ]
    file-close
    end
```

The list lines will contain all of the lines of the file, Then use a foreach on the list to select each element at a time to execute.
I am aware of the primitive "read-from-string" but it only seems to work from values rather than commands.
Is there any method of achieving this or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

If the command is a reporter, you can use `runresult`, otherwise, you could use `run`

See: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#run

For example:

```
show runresult "3 + 2"
```

It's a little weird that you're storing commands in a text file, why not just use an nls file to store the extra commands?